# How do you load WordPress from an external script when using MultiSite?

Tags: multisite, cron, scripts, wp-load.php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using WordPress functions on other sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40586/using-wordpress-functions-on-other-sites)

I have an external script that needs to load up WordPress in order to have access to WordPress functionality.

In the past I have successfully done this by including wp-load.php. However, when using MultiSite, this does not work. It appears to be logged as a bug [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14913).

Does anyone have any work arounds or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I posted [a way to accomplish this here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40590/12324). Essentially, my suggestion is to create a sort of API for your WP installation to maintain orthogonality between your systems.